# Disable alt-tab (option-tab) instead of command-tab

Tags: macos, keyboard, dock, remote-desktop

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.4 on a Macbook Pro and somehow alt-tab is switching between the applications from Dock. I would like alt-tab to work within RDP (Windows) only.

I don't know how (or if) did I enable that (i do not have KeyRemap4Mac or anything like that).

Is alt(option)-tab supposed to work as default?

Any ideas how I can disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've managed to change your keyboard mappings.  Assuming you haven't installed 3rd party mapping software, the quickest fix is to restore the mappings back to default.

SystemPreferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Keyboard & Text Input -> Restore Defaults

Most likely one of the "Move focus to X" options is set to alt-tab

Comment: Yes, thanks! I tried setting "option-tab" to some other shortcut and noticed I had at some point set it to some other obscure action.
(sorry for the late reply, I somehow didn't get the StackExchange notifications and had just given up on it :P)

Answer (score 2):

Also check if you don't have both keys swapped in **System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier Keys**.